# touches.anyObject() no longer working

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've got an error that I don't know how to handle. In

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        //Some code here

        let touch = touches.anyObject() as! UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        sceneTouched(touchLocation)

}
```

I get the error "Set" does not have a member named 'anyObject'". I've searched all along the internet and found nothing. I know it is related with some recent changes in Swift but I don't know how to aproach it. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    var touch : UITouch!
    touch = touches.first as? UITouch
    let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
    sceneTouched(touchLocation)
 }
```

Comment: Worked woders! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note that Swift Set type does not have anyObject method. You can either cast it to NSSet and then use anyObject method or simply use first? that is available to all CollectionType in Swift.

```
let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
```